# Issue facing while returning values from child to parent page via javascript. It is returning object and i want the value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function in which if a user select future date then a pop up will appear and that pop up will contain an text box and a button.The user enter the value in the text box and click on the Button of child pop up.I want to capture those value in the parent window but i m not able to do it.

Below is the javascript which i had written:-

```
 function CheckDateEalier(sender, args)
     {
        var toDate = new Date();
        toDate.setMinutes(0);
        toDate.setSeconds(0);
        toDate.setHours(0);
        toDate.setMilliseconds(0);
        if (sender._selectedDate < toDate)
         {
            alert("You can't select day earlier than today! In Case if you are selecting Previous date then, By default it will take current Date.");
            sender._selectedDate = toDate;
            //set the date back to the current date
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
        if (sender._selectedDate > toDate) {
            var timeSpent = window.open("EnterTimeSpent.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=320,height=100");
            document.getElementById('<%= hiddenFieldFutureDateSelectTimeSpent.ClientID%>').value = timeSpent;
        }
    }
```

javascript on Child page:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Parent() {
    var timespent = Input.elements["timespent"].value; 
    //window.opener.UpdateValues(3);
    window.returnValue = timespent;
    self.close();
}
```

Child Page Code Behind:-

```
<form name="Input" method="post" action="">
     <table>
       <tr>
       <td><input type="text" name="timespent" style="font-size:small;font-weight:bold;"></input>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
       <input type="button" value="Submit"  class="button small green rounded"   onClick="Parent()"></input>
       </td></tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

When i am debugging then i found that on the parent page , i m not able to capture the timespent send from child,It is displaying it as object.Please help me out that what the mistake i m doing and how i capture the value of textbox of child page in parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use 'prompt' which already has this functionality;

var t=prompt("timespent","");

If you need styling you could use jprompt(http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs)

Comment: I am not using prompt because of design and it appears only on the Top left position of the screen.But the jprompt is suggested is really good. Thanks